# Angular - How to test a method that returns an Observable<boolean>

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a method that returns an Observable :

```
public hasFiltersSelected(): Observable<boolean> {
return this.store.pipe(
  select(selectSelectedFilters),
  map(obj => Object.keys(obj).length > 0)
);
```

}

Does anyone know how should I do the unit testing for this one ? tyvm

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. Where 'service' is an instance containing hasFilterSelected()

```
it('should return observable of true', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'hasFilterSelected');
    service.hasFilterSelected().subscribe((resp) => {
        expect(resp).toEqual(true);
    }
    expect(service.hasFilterSelected).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```